# Is there a mitzvah of Sippur Yetzias Mitzraim all night long?

Tags: halacha, passover, passover-seder-hagada, evening-night

Once the *seder* has ended, does the *mitzvah* to tell the story of the Exodus continue all night long?

I am familiar with the various arguments in the Gemara (with R. Elazar, R. Akivah, R. Gamliel, and so forth), but am curious if there is any normative *halachic* conclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch in siman 481 writes:

A person is required to involve themselves in the laws of Pesach and Yetzias Mitzraim and discuss the signs and wonders that Hashem did for our forefathers until he is 'caught' by sleep.

Be'er Hagola points out this is all from the Tur in the name of the Tosefta, based on the story With Rabi Eleazar and Rabi Yehoshua etc.

The Ramma in siman 476 quotes the Maharil who warned not to eat or drink too much or become intoxicated for fear that he will fall asleep immediately. Mishna Berurah #7 points to the aforementioned Tosefta as the reason to avoid falling asleep right away.